# Symfony always throw OptimisticLockException in my custom console command

Tags: symfony, doctrine

My code in console command

Constructor

```
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, $name = null)
{
    parent::__construct($name);

    $this->em = $em;
}
```

... And in my executte command always OptimisticLockException

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {

$repository = $this->em->getRepository(ProductData::class);
$product = $repository->findOneBy(array('code' => $data[0]));

$product->setName($data[1]);
$product->setDesc($data[2]);
$product->setStockLevel((float)$data[3]);
$product->setPrice((float)$data[4]);
$this->em->flush();    }
```

I need help please

Comment: can you show $product entity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that if the model has @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks ()
And when I updated the model, the function

```
public function onPreUpdate()
{
    $this->setTimestamp(new \DateTime('now'));
}
```

work incorrectly. Update function looking for a model not only on the id, but also on the timestamp. Why? I don't known:

```
UPDATE tblProductData SET strProductName = ?, stmTimestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE intProductDataId = ? AND stmTimestamp = ? ["qqqq",8,"2018-05-10 15:44:21"]
```

And therefore there was such an error, because the model was not found